# Returning count of all points within specified range to single point using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, proximity

This may be more of a SQL fundamentals question but I'm sure somebody on here has encountered this before.

I have a database of geospacial data (around 4 million points) using PostgreSQL/PostGIS

I would like to add a value to indicate how many of the other points in the table are within a specified range (5km) to that row value.

```
SELECT count(geom) 
FROM geom_points
WHERE ST_DistanceSphere(geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(long, lat),4326)) < 5000
```

The following works for a single row but I would like to be able to run this value for all rows and append the value to the row as a count.

I'm not really worried how long it will take as it is a function I intend to run once per year.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a column and update with a self-join:

```
ALTER TABLE <table>
  ADD COLUMN <neighbor_count> INT
;

UPDATE <table> AS t
  SET <neighbor_count> = (
    SELECT COUNT(s.*) - 1
    FROM   <table> AS s
    WHERE  ST_DWithin(t.geom, s.geom, <distance>)
  )
;
```

Here

- `ST_DWithin` is the better choice, as it implements an index lookup natively
- `COUNT(s.*) - 1` subtracts the current point from the count; this is cheaper than excluding by `<id>`
- `<distance>` refers to your distance in units of the given CRS; *see below*

---

This procedure is efficient only when utilizing a spatial index, and the proximity search requires either a suitable projection or the `GEOGRAPHY` type, if you are using a geographic reference system, to be able to use *meter* based units.

Since your data seems to be referenced in EPSG:4326, I'd suggest to add a functional index on a `CAST` to `GEOGRAPHY` to get results within your lifetime:

```
CREATE INDEX ON <table>
  USING GIST( (geom::GEOGRAPHY) )   -- double parens!
;

VACUUM ANALYZE <table>;
```

and run

```
UPDATE <table> AS t
  SET <neighbor_count> = (
    SELECT COUNT(s.*) - 1
    FROM   <table> AS s
    WHERE  ST_DWithin(t.geom::GEOGRAPHY, s.geom::GEOGRAPHY, 5000)
  )
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a lateral join. The trick is to use the same table twice: once for the source, and once for counting nearby points.

Be aware that `ST_DistanceSphere` doesn't use indexes. Instead you can cast your points to `geography`, create an index on the geographies, and use `st_dwithin` instead.

```sql
create index geogidx on geom_points  USING gist((geom::geography));

select a.*, sub.cnt
from geom_points a,
lateral  (select count(*) as cnt 
    from geom_points b
    where st_dwithin(a.geom::geography, b.geom::geography,5000)
    and a.geo_id <> b.geo_id  --Optionaly prevent a point from counting itself
 ) sub;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would typically do this with a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` and a `SELF JOIN`. Then on the query, you would select from the materialized view and you could find your results (since this will be slow). First, storing `lat` and `long` on the row is stupid, as it doesn't make any sense without an SRID and it's more difficult to index and query. So let's fix that.

Sample data (where you're at)

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo AS
SELECT 1 AS id, 1::float AS lat, 2::float AS long;
```

Changing to a geopgrahy point on the table,

```sql
BEGIN;
  ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN geog geography;
  UPDATE foo SET geog = ST_MakePoint(long,lat)::geography;
  ALTER TABLE foo DROP COLUMN lat, DROP COLUMN long;
  CREATE INDEX ON foo USING gist ( geog );
COMMIT;
```

Now to get what you want you'll want to use the query with [`ST_DWithin`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html), note this will use an index.

```
SELECT f1.*, count(*) FROM foo AS f1
INNER JOIN foo AS f2 ON ST_DWithin(f1.geog, f2.geog, 5000)
GROUP BY f1.id, f1.geog;
```

But that may not be fast enough to run in production, to solve your problem you can create a [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html),

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW foo_count AS
  SELECT f1.*, count(*) FROM foo AS f1
  INNER JOIN foo AS f2 ON ST_DWithin(f1.geog, f2.geog, 5000)
  GROUP BY f1.id, f1.geog;
```

Now once a year you just need to run,

```sql
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW foo_count;
```

The advantage being you don't have to remember how you did it, and it creates a discrete layer separating your data from your generated view.