# Calculating point density as attribute in point layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, point, distance, density

For each point in my layer, I would like to calculate the number of other points within x distance, and for that information to be in the attribute table.

I have a method but it is a few steps. As it seems like a basic but common issue, I was just wondering if there was a one-step method/tool I am missing in QGIS.

My current steps are:

1. Create circular buffers around all points at x distance
2. Count points in polygon
3. Spatial join resulting counts polygons back to the original points layer
4. extra step - field calculator to get counts/buffer area to get points/km2

Comment: I think you way is the best

Comment: The only "one step" approach I can see would be a Python script, which in this case especially would only be a few lines using `QgsFeatureRequest.setDistanceWithin`

Comment: I would rather join the count using the ID, otherwise you'd join the number of points within a polygon to all points within said polygon. Otherwise this works fine. Alternatively you could use `heatmap kernel density estimation` and add the density data back to your points.

Answer (score 4):

The best one-step method I can think of is using the [Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#qgisfieldcalculator) to directly create a new attribute with this expression:

```
array_length(
    overlay_nearest(
        @layer, 
        $id,
        max_distance:=20, -- set distance here
        limit:=count($id)
    )
)
```

---

*Remark:* Unfortunately, the `limit` argument doesn't work using `-1` when applied to the same layer (returning zero instead of all matching features). To address this, simply use the number of points contained in the layer with `count($id)`.

Comment: This seems a bit of a weak best one-step solution if either it needs 2 steps or it forces you to set a parameter that depending on your data could give you an inaccurate result.

Comment: See edited answer that solves this issue

Answer (score 3):

There is a possibility of using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

Let's assume there is a point layer called *'points_in_polygon'*, see the image below.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible *to calculate the number of other points within x distance, and for that information to be in the attribute table*.

```sql
SELECT p1.*, COUNT(p2.id) AS WITHIN50
FROM "points_in_polygon" AS p1
LEFT JOIN "points_in_polygon" AS p2 ON
      NOT ST_Equals(p1.geometry, p2.geometry)
      AND ST_Distance(p1.geometry, p2.geometry) <= 50 -- this value can be changed
GROUP BY p1.id
```

It encapsulates two functions i.e. [`ST_Distance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) and [`ST_Equals`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Equals.html).

Unfortunatelly the [`ST_DWithin`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) function is not implemented in Virtual Layers, however, another solution will be available through the SpatialLite [`PtDistWithin`](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-5.0.1.html#p13) function, as was suggested by @BERA.

```sql
SELECT p1.*, COUNT(p2.id) AS WITHIN50
FROM "points_in_polygon" AS p1
LEFT JOIN "points_in_polygon" AS p2 ON
      NOT ST_Equals(p1.geometry, p2.geometry)
      AND PtDistWithin(p1.geometry, p2.geometry, 50.0) -- this value can be changed
GROUP BY p1.id
```

In both cases, the output point layer with its attribute table will look like:

[image: result]

*Note:* More sophisticated solutions can be performed using the PostGIS, see the first reference.

---

**References:**

- [Returning count of all points within specified range to single point using PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/417984/returning-count-of-all-points-within-specified-range-to-single-point-using-postg)
- [Listing all functions available in QGIS's Virtual Layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382795/listing-all-functions-available-in-qgiss-virtual-layer)

Answer (score 1):

One-step solution using PyQGIS script:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsFeatureRequest

# "points" is the name of the layer in legend
layer_name = "points"

# Distance within which to look for neighbors 
distance = 100

# Field name (already in layer) into which the result will be saved
field_name = "field_x"

point_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
idx_field_to_change = point_layer.fields().indexFromName(field_name)

dict_attribute_change = {}

for point_feature in point_layer.getFeatures():
    point_geometry = point_feature.geometry()
    request = QgsFeatureRequest().setDistanceWithin(point_geometry, distance)
    dict_attribute_change[point_feature.id()] = {idx_field_to_change: 0}

    for other_point_feature in point_layer.getFeatures(request):
        
        # comment the next two lines if you want to count the origin point 
        # as being a neighbor of itself
        if other_point_feature.id() == point_feature.id():
            continue
            
        dict_attribute_change[point_feature.id()][idx_field_to_change] += 1

point_layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(dict_attribute_change)
```

Comment: what is the `other_point_feature` ? maybe you meant the `point_feature` ?

Comment: @Taras Thanks, there was a typo I edited.